# Removing conditional duplicate string lists from an ordered nested list

Tags: python

I have a nested list composed of two types of list entries: ['Vendor ID', 'Vendor Name'] and ['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$ Amount']. Sometimes the Vendor ID: Vendor Name lists repeat, but the Functional Amount Not Invoiced lists do not - they contain one list related to the Vendor ID lists:

```
[['110220VOLTS0001', 'Vendor1'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$56.97'],
['2729426', 'Vendor2'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$1,000.00'],
['2955510', 'Vendor3'],
['2955510', 'Vendor3'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$329.00'],
['3466873', 'Vendor4'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$0.48']]
```

I am trying to remove duplicate entries for the Vendor ID: Vendor Name lines (such as ['2955510':'Vendor3']. I tried using OrderedDict, but because there is more than one list that starts with 'Functional Amount Not Invoiced', I can't use an OrderedDict in this case. I also tried using set() on the list, but I received an error message about being an unhashable type.

I'm looking for suggestions how I can remove duplicate entries in this particular nested list. Expected output is below:

```
[['110220VOLTS0001', 'Vendor1'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$56.97'],
['2729426', 'Vendor2'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$1,000.00'],
['2955510', 'Vendor3'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$329.00'],
['3466873', 'Vendor4'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$0.48']]
```

Comment: One obvious solution is to simply remove any sublist that is identical to its predecessor, and where the first item in the sublist is not "Functional Amount Not Invoiced:".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You are right to use sets

You do indeed want a "set of things seen so far", so you can prevent those from being stored again. But you can't use the list itself as an entry in the set, because lists can't be hashed.

However it is easy to do an equivalent of that. Convert each list into a unique thing *is* hashable, e.g. concatenating the strings of which the list is composed. That *thing*, the "key", can then be hashed, so you can put that into the set.

As a matter of habit I usually interpose some unusual character in between the strings when I am concatenating them to make a key. This is to prevent ["2729361", "1-2-2014"] and ["272936", "11-2-2014"] from being converted into the same key, "27293611-2-2014". In your case it is not necessary because there will always be the word "Vendor" exactly once, and at the beginning of the second string. However I have put in a "~" just keep myself disciplined in not relying on some assumptions.

#### Limitations

This approach relies on being able to create a set large enough to store the keys of every case you find. I am pretty sure this will be the case for you,

If, on the other hand, you are Jeff Bezos writing code that runs Amazon.com, and needing it to run on an Arduino, maybe you can't fit the set into RAM. But you can take a simplified approach. As long as you know that

- there are only duplicates and no higher counts
- any duplicates are *always* successive entries and not more widely spaced

... then you can take a shortcut, of getting rid of the `set` and only comparing with the key of the last entry. And of course you could then read the file in line-by-line and write the output line-by-line, so you never have to have either the whole input file or output file in memory.

```
things = [['110220VOLTS0001', 'Vendor1'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$56.97'],
['2729426', 'Vendor2'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$1,000.00'],
['2955510', 'Vendor3'],
['2955510', 'Vendor3'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$329.00'],
['3466873', 'Vendor4'],
['Functional Amount Not Invoiced:', '$0.48']]

def key(thing):
    return thing[0]+"~"+thing[1]

keys_seen = set()
result = []

for thing in things:
    thing_key = key(thing)

    if thing_key not in keys_seen:
        keys_seen.add(thing_key)
        result.append(thing)

print(result)
```